# Show executed .m-File after click on gui - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a quite fancy GUI from a toolbox with a lot of .m-files in the folder. Since I want to manipulate a certain .m-file I would like to know if there is a command that shows me which .m-file is executed when I click a button.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `mfilename` returns the file name of the currently running MATLAB function. If you insert that command throughout your multiple `.m` files, you would be able to see whenever any of them were executed.